# Get total count of assertions made in a React app using Jest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, istanbul

I am currently using the built-in Jest testing environment that comes with the generated boilerplate by create-react-app. With Jest's integration with Istanbul, one can get the unit test coverage by total number of *statements*, *functions*, *lines*, and *branches* covered. Aside from these, is there any way to get the **total number of assertions** used in all the unit test files? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not aware if jest has this functionality built in, but we can probably mimic this with grep and wc.

**Grep searches files for specific text.**

```
 grep [options] PATTERN [FILE...]

 -r --recursive
 -c --count
 -i --ignore-case
 --include=PATTERN
   Recurse in directories only searching file matching PATTERN.
```

**wc - print newline, word, and byte counts for each file**

```
wc [OPTION]... [FILE]...

-l, --lines
print the newline counts
```

---

Print the count of "expect" pattern matches in each file:

`grep -r -i -c --include \*.test.js "expect" .` matches

Print the sum of total "expect" pattern matches.

`grep -r -i --include \*.test.js "expect" . | wc - l`

Comment: I am actually looking for an API reference from Instanbul and Jest, and this is not it. But, it gave me an idea of a workaround so I gave it an upvote. Thanks, anyway!